# How do you inlay a brass corner ornament using handtools only?

Tags: hand-tools, inlay

I'm working on a campaign-style jewelry box, and am curious about the best way to inlay a corner guard that has a curve in it.

My plan is to make a full size photo copy of the hardware, then rubber cement them to the corners to begin mortising out the profile of the brass.

However, for the curve, I'm not sure exactly how to go about it. I have standard square bench chisels and a router plane, but is there a better tool for the job to tackle this arc profile?

Unfortunately, I'm in an apartment and can't use any power tools, otherwise I'd likely use a palm router and pattern bit.

Thanks for the help!

The brass I'm looking to use:

[image: Curved brass corner guard]

Example of mounted brass campaign hardware:
[image: example of campaign furniture with corner brass ornament]

Comment: If you're working with hand tools only, you should take a look at materials from handtool-heavy carpenters like Roy Underhill ("The Woodwright's Shop") and Christopher Schwarz, if you haven't already. (The particular reason I mention those two is that there's an episode of the Woodwright's Shop with Christopher Schwarz as a guest which installs exactly those sorts of corners on a campaign chest, IIRC.)

Comment: I would love to see CS doing this install. If you can find a link to this episode, it would be much appreciated!

Comment: Looks like it's [Season 34 episode 9](https://www.pbs.org/video/woodwrights-shop-fitting-brass/) ("Fitting Brass" - link to PBS site, if it works for you.) Corner brass starts at 22:00 min.

Comment: This explained it perfectly, and was also a joy to watch. Thank you!

Comment: You're welcome, I guess :-/

Answer (score 9):

Your chisels and router plane are completely adequate tools for the job.   The curve you have to cut are convex in the wood, so approximating with small chisel nibbles is perfectly feasible.  I would proceed as follows: Mount support blocks flush with the final surface on the outside of the corner, so you have an adequate plane to support your router plane.    Make outline cuts with chisels that leave a small margin on the curve.   Route out the waste.   Remove the blocks.   Now, nibble to the convex line with a small (say 1/4" or 6mm) chisel with clean cuts, removing the remaining waste with flat chisel cuts to the line.   Work carefully, and there is no reason to not have a near perfect fit.

Answer (score 5):

> My plan is to make a full size photo copy of the hardware, then rubber cement them to the corners to begin mortising out the profile of the brass.

I think this is a good plan for the top profile (do be sure to confirm that the photocopy is dead-on 1:1 before proceeding though) but I think not for the sides — wrapping over the corner so to speak may introduce an error that would be a pain to fix after the fact.

Instead use a marking gauge for the height, measurement taken directly from the hardware. In addition to being super-accurate this will give you a scored or cut line to register your chisels with when you get to the perimeter.

This is an adaptation of the technique used to mortise-in for hinges if it would help to look at some of the (many) guides to doing that in books an online.

> I have standard square bench chisels... but is there a better tool for the job to tackle this arc profile?

In traditional hand-tool technique convex curves were often cut using normal chisels, since many curves were outside the range of what was available in outcannel gouges.

Trim back to your line and test fit incrementally and you'll get there. You could create a custom sanding block to sand this surface but it may not really be necessary once the facets get small enough — you'll be taking tiny shavings toward the end, slivers really.

See [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lDEGt.jpg) for how to hold the chisel for these sorts of paring cuts.

Oh and BTW, *use the widest chisel you feel comfortable wielding for this*; it's much easier to judge the tangent of a wide chisel than a narrow one. Just be careful when you get to the ends that you don't knick the flat 'returns' with a corner because you're so focused on the curve (very easy to have tunnel vision doing this sort of task, DAMHIK).

**Tip for the router, to, uh, prevent tipping**
I would mount a much wider ancillary base AKA subbase to it so you can more easily keep it upright and firmly against the working surface. If you make it asymmetrical (as lots of power-router bases are now) mount a handle on the opposite end so you can press down there, see pictured examples [in previous Answer](https://woodworking.stackexchange.com/questions/13636/aligning-table-top-veneer-with-solid-wood-frame/13638#13638).

Although such bases for hand routers were traditionally made of wood (even before the days of plywood) and wood is still a perfectly viable choice use Perspex if you can get it, it has lots of advantages. Acrylic or polycarbonate sheet can be cut, shaped and drilled with standard power tools.

---

> ...pattern bit

Just for reference, unless you created a pattern to follow that had the exact inset required this wouldn't do it because of the bearing. I'd use a plain straight-cutting bit here for all surfaces (working perpendicular for all, same as you would naturally do for the top).

It may be worth nothing that a lot of woodworkers would use a router to hog out the waste using a powered router (both for speed and for the assurance of exact depth) but still trim the edges by hand with chisels/gouges.

Comment: *confirm that the photocopy is dead-on 1:1* -- twice, if you're using a rather wet glue, as paper stretches when wet - confirm before gluing and check after.  I use [glue sticks](https://www.prittworld.co.uk/en/products/glue/glue-sticks/original-pritt-glue-stick.html) for sticking down templates on smooth wood, when I'm not worried about removing the template afterwards and they don't wet the paper enough for it to stretch or wrinkle

Comment: @ChrisH, that's a good point. I'd probably use spray adhesive as I have some I need to finish before the can loses pressure, but I'd use glue sticks if I had them. If I did a lot of work that involved sticking down templates I'd make a point of getting some Pritt stick as it's just so much less hassle and no offensive odour!

Comment: I've also used spray adhesive for similar tasks - the repositionable sort is especially useful. With kid's craft more common than woodworking  in this house we have plenty of Pritt sticks.  Another option is to print 1:1 onto Post-it photo paper, but then you're talking CAD rather than photcopying